# php isImage($url) using stream_get_meta_data doesn't work with local file path

Tags: php, image, stream

is it possible to adapt this function so it also works with local file path's?

$meta contains the following:
Array ( [wrapper_type] => plainfile [stream_type] => STDIO [mode] => rb [unread_bytes] => 0 [seekable] => 1 [uri] => C:\imgs\232434.jpg [timed_out] => [blocked] => 1 [eof] => )

$meta["wrapper_data"] doesn't exist.

```
function isImage($url)
  {
     $params = array('http' => array(
                  'method' => 'HEAD'
               ));
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
     $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
     if (!$fp) 
        return false;  // Problem with url

    $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    if ($meta === false)
    {
        fclose($fp);
        return false;  // Problem reading data from url
    }

    $wrapper_data = $meta["wrapper_data"];
    if(is_array($wrapper_data)){
      foreach(array_keys($wrapper_data) as $hh){
          if (substr($wrapper_data[$hh], 0, 19) == "Content-Type: image") // strlen("Content-Type: image") == 19 
          {
            fclose($fp);
            return true;
          }
      }
    }

    fclose($fp);
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best if you use [getimagesize](http://il.php.net/getimagesize) to detect if local/URL file is image or not.

On failure, FALSE is returned.
This is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @minimihi: suggested to use "exif_imagetype" instead of "getimagesize".
I can't review his edit but you can use exif_imagetype instead, it should be faster

Comment: actually i am looking for acurate detection. i don't care about speed really, cos it is always some hundred miliseconds in my server.